# Finding consecutive patterns (with SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

A table `consecutive` in PostgreSQL:
Each `se_id` has an `idx`
from 0 up to 100 - here 0 to 9.

The search pattern:

```
SELECT *
FROM consecutive
WHERE val_3_bool = 1
AND val_1_dur > 4100 AND val_1_dur < 5900
```

[image: sorce_table]

Now I'm looking for the longest consecutive appearance of this pattern
for each `p_id` - and the `AVG` of the counted `val_1_dur`.

[image: result_table]

Is it possible to calculate this in pure SQL?

[table as txt](http://d.pr/f/4kF5bH)
["Result" as txt](http://d.pr/f/p90Too)

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands+postgresql

Answer (score 3):

One method is the difference of row numbers approach to get the sequences for each:

```
select pid, count(*) as in_a_row, sum(val1_dur) as dur
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by pid order by idx) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by pid, val3_bool order by idx) as seqnum_d
      from consecutive t
     ) t
group by (seqnun - seqnum_d), pid, val3_bool;
```

If you are looking specifically for "1" values, then add `where val3_bool = 1` to the outer query.  To understand why this works, I would suggest that you stare at the results of the subquery, so you can understand why the difference defines the consecutive values.

You can then get the max using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (pid) t.*
from (select pid, count(*) as in_a_row, sum(val1_dur) as dur
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by pid order by idx) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by pid, val3_bool order by idx) as seqnum_d
            from consecutive t
           ) t
      group by (seqnun - seqnum_d), pid, val3_bool;
     ) t
order by pid, in_a_row desc;
```

The `distinct on` does not require an additional level of subquery, but I think that makes the logic clearer.

Comment: Sounds interesing. ;)
But I’m looking only for the consecutive matching of a specific pattern.

Comment: @Teletubbi-OSX . . . This does what you want.  Just add the `where` clause to the query before the `group by`, as explained in the answer.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks. 
But this procedure is a bit slow. It takes ~30sec. (table size 750MB).

Answer (score 0):

There are Window Functions, that enable you to compare one line with the previous and next one.

https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-window-functions/
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

As seen on [How to compare the current row with next and previous row in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974866/how-to-compare-the-current-row-with-next-and-previous-row-in-postgresql) and [Filtering by window function result in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042525/filtering-by-window-function-result-in-postgresql)